# Why does .5 become 1.0 when rounding? Shouldn't it be 0.5?

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode

I'm trying to learn C++.
I'm using Mac xCode v.  11.4.1 
on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)
Processor:  2.9 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7
Memory:  8GB

```
while (c < .9)
{
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << "\nc = " << c << '\n';
    array.push_back(c);
    c = round ((c *10)/10);
    std::cout << "After rounding, c = " << c << '\n';
}
std::cout << "\nSize of the vector \'array\' = " << array.size() << '\n';
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i ++ )
{
    std::cout << "\narray[" << i << "] = " << array[i] << std::endl;
}
```

My results:

```
.1

c = 0.1
After rounding, c = 0
.2

c = 0.2
After rounding, c = 0
.3

c = 0.3
After rounding, c = 0
.4

c = 0.4
After rounding, c = 0
.5

c = 0.5
After rounding, c = 1

Size of the vector 'array' = 5

array[0] = 0.1

array[1] = 0.2

array[2] = 0.3

array[3] = 0.4

array[4] = 0.5
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: did you mean `round(c *10)/10`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yeah I was just thinking the same thing..

Comment: BTW how is your `round` printing a non-integer value?? Please fix typos in your code!

Comment: @AlanBirtles yeah sorry for that... Actually an edit was made to the question which fixed that part! Earlier the console was unformatted hence it was appearing like 0.2 and 0.3 instead of 0 \n .2 and 0 \n .3

Comment: Yes. round(c*10)/10.  I thought that round ((10*10/10);  would do the same thing based on parens.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That's just how [`std::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) is defined.

> Computes the nearest integer value to arg (in floating-point format), rounding halfway cases away from zero, regardless of the current rounding mode.

You might want to take a look at [`std::floor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor), and [`std::ceil`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil), since you seem to be expecting some behaviour like that.